# What does 'Highest School' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

When filling up my personal information for a job application, I'm asked about my `Highest School` and `Second Highest School`. After this field, they ask for `Highest Degree`.

Does `Highest School` mean the type of institution (High School, University) or the name of it?

Comment: "Highest School" and "Second Highest School" is not idiomatic and sounds like something a non-native speaker would write.  It should be something like "highest level of schooling".  Also, "second highest level of schooling" is meaningless.  It sounds like they're confused about what they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this would be worded as "highest school completed", but it is sometimes shorted to "highest school". Generally, the answer would be the level, e.g. if you have a Masters degree but not a Ph.D you would put down "Master's Degree".

Unless there are spaces for further details like degree attained, field of study, years attended, or GPA. Then I would assume that it is asking for the specific institution.

Comment: Yes. Seems to me that this is usually worded, "highest level of schooling completed". I think the "highest school" in the United States is probably the University of Denver, 5280 feet above sea level. :-)

Comment: Or maybe the highest school in America is the University of New Hampshire, where reportedly 29% of the students use illegal drugs. :-)